# Why is my href directory not working in my reactjs project?

Tags: html, reactjs, hyperlink, href

I am trying to go to this file when the "Join Now" button is clicked but it doesn't seem to be working. As you can see on line 9 in the image below, I have an href for '/auth/login' and it is not working when I click on the button 'Join Now' but rather nothing comes up. I have tried different directories such as '/src/app/auth/login' and it is still not working. I think it is definitely an easy fix but I am a beginner and lost. Any tips would be greatly appreciated.

[image: My code and specifically my href on line 9]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

/auth/login is not routable, check out the doc here:
https://nextjs.org/docs/app/building-your-application/routing/colocation

1. put your component folder into the src folder
2. try this folder structure under auth:
   auth/
   login/
   page.js

   where the page.js content should be your current login.js content

Comment: wow. youre a legend. that worked. But I have no idea why that worked, could you please explain please?

Comment: it is just the way next.js routing work, if you read the doc in the given link.